# Xpath getting elements from flat HTML hierarchy

Tags: php, xpath

**HTML structure:**

```
<div class="title">
    <h1>Some title</h1>
</div>    
<div class="row">something</div>

... (repeats the same structure)

<div class="title">
    <h1>Another title</h1>
</div>    
<div class="row anotherclass">1 something</div>
<div class="row">2 something</div>
<div class="row">3 something</div>

<div class="title">
    <h1>Some title</h1>
</div>    
<div class="row">something</div>
```

How can I get all the divs (with the "row" class") where the previous title (h1) matches my `$search`?

What I have right now (doesn't work for the last element and it also doesn't stop at the next title):

```
//div[child::h1[contains(text(), "<?php echo $search ?>")]]
/following-sibling::div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " title ")]
/preceding-sibling::div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " row ")]
```

**If I search for "Another title", the output should be:**

```
<div class="row anotherclass">1 something</div>
<div class="row">2 something</div>
<div class="row">3 something</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long one:

```xml
//div[contains(concat(" ",@class," ")," row ")][preceding-sibling::div[contains(concat(" ",@class," ")," title ")][1][contains(h1,"<?php echo $search ?>")]]
```

I'll break it into pieces:

You want all divs which have a class row...

```xml
//div[contains(concat(" ",@class," ")," row ")]
```

whose **first** preceding-sibling with a class title...

```xml
[preceding-sibling::div[contains(concat(" ",@class," ")," title ")][1]
```

has an h1 that contains your search query

```xml
[contains(h1,"<?php echo $search ?>")]]
```